# Sitecore personalization based on at least two pages visited from set of pages

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, personalization, rules-engine

I am looking to specify a personalization rules in `Sitecore 8.2` where at least two pages are visited from a specific set of pages on the websites for example:

```
Content 
  - Home
    - car loans (1)
        - Apply for car loan (2)
     - Home loans
         - apply for home loan
      - I want to
            - buy a new car (3)
      - get help
            - Buying a car (4)
```

From the pages marked as 1 - 4, the rule should be valid when 2 out of those 4 pages are visited during the interaction. The pages doesn't belong to a unique template so the template would be used on multiple pages through out the website. Can I use any of the out of the box rules to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mahendra almost has it right, but for the rule that should be triggered if 2 or more pages have been visited, you would need to use a combination of Profiles and Values.

1. Create a `Profile Card` for this rule to use and add a `Profile Key`
2. Go to each page, and using the `Profile Card` button, edit the profile card and set the value for the `Profile Key` to 1:
   [image: Add the profile key value]
3. Now personalize the renderings you want and add the rule: `where the value of the specific profile key in the contact behavior profile compares to value`:
   [image]

Now, when your users browse the site, each time they hit one of those pages, the `Profile Key` you created will increase in value by the value you set (`1`) - then when that value is high enough, it will trigger the personalized content.

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive personalization is a feature that dynamically changes the content of your website based on the visitor’s behavior on your website during a visit. Adaptive
personalization uses visitor profiles and pattern-card matching to dynamically adapt the content shown to visitors in real-time. You can set adaptive personalization
rules in the Rules Set Editor based on your requirements. But if you are specific to a few pages and want it in the same way you can make use of Goals.
You need to do the following things :

1. Create a Goal for each page in the Goals - `/sitecore/system/Marketing Center/Goals`
2. Set the Goal/s on your pages.
3. Create a Rule with a condition similar as 
   `"where the specific goal was triggered during the current visit"`, and use the appropriate Action based on your requirement. In the same rule, you can add multiple rules since you will have different Goals to check.
4. On your target page, you need to have the created rule checked on a Sublayout / Rendering